# Skip the login page of jaas module

Tags: jsf, jaas

I have created a project that contains two login mechanisms:

- The first one is the first authentication mechanism that uses a simple login page (get a user if exists from the database using a function `findUser`)
- And the second authentication mechanism is the login mechanism offered by JAAS (j_security_check)

> Basically I am trying to achieve this goal: when the user will
>   authenticate successfully (in the first login page) he  should be
>   able to skip the second page login (offered by JAAS) without having
>   to reenter his username and password in login form (j_security_chek
>   ) i prefer that the login page will not be shown at all and jump to the resources pages directly.

I need some suggestion, and if the question is not clear enough please do not hesitate to notify that, thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Ideally, you should be using the new JEE programmatic login, available in Servlet 3.0. Alternatively, you could experiment with creating the `HttpSession`, after successfully authenticating using the first mechanism (the idea being that the container will not attempt to reauthenticate if the user provides a valid JSESSION_ID in subsequent requests)

Comment: in the link that refer a protected Resource  Admin/index ( normaly the link that make jaas invoke login page ) i tried to pass **j_username** and **j_password* with **post** method , so that  can in the same time access the resources and submit the form login .

`<form method="post" action="#{moduleBean.userBean.navigateByRole()}
/j_security_check"> <input type="hidden" name="j_username" value="#{moduleBean.userBean.currentUser.username}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="j_password" value="#{moduleBean.userBean.currentUser.password}" /> <input type="submit" value="Module Production"/></form>`.

Comment: (sorry for the format but i have no remaining spaces) , so when i click the link , the loginerror page shown ( knowing that login & password are correct )

Answer (score 0):

I founded a temporary solution, it works very well. So it's simple I just filled the j_username & j_password with values ​​comming from the first login mechanism (the first one) and what i do is that i had created a function with javascript ( **accessResource()** ) That submiting the login form (the form with action = j_security_check) **on load** of the current page

**jaasLogin.xhtml :**

```
<h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <script>
            function accessResource(){
                document.forms["loginForm"].submit();
            }
        </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body class="metro" onload="accessResource()">
.......
.......
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check" class="form bg-login">
                <div class="container span5" name="container">
                    <h:outputLabel>Utilisateur</h:outputLabel>
                    <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
                        <input type="text" name="j_username" value="#{moduleBean.userBean.username}"/>
                        <h:commandButton type="button" class="btn-clear" tabindex="-1"></h:commandButton>
                    </div>
                    <h:outputLabel>Mot de passe</h:outputLabel>
                    <div class="input-control password" data-role="input-control">
                        <input  type="password" name="j_password" value="#{moduleBean.userBean.password}" />
                        <h:commandButton type="button" class="btn-reveal" tabindex="-1"></h:commandButton>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <input name="login" type="submit" value="LOGIN" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

wish that help you